# Software interrupts, Keil MCB1700 evaluation board

Tags: embedded, arm, keil, rtx

I try to develop programs for MCB1700 evaluation board.
Is it possible to use software interrupts (SWI) without RTOS RTX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, except that on a Cortex M3 processor you'll use `SVC` instead of `SWI`.  You don't need to use an RTOS to use this functionality.

The exception handler will be a little bit different than with `SWI` because of register stacking on entry to the exception.

Also be aware that unlike `SWI`, you cannot invoke `SVC` while running a `SVC` handler (whereas you could "nest" `SWI`s)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just a normal Cotex-M3 processor.  You can use any RTOS you want and still be able to use the SWI features of the Cortex.